# Chef bootstrapping on Azure doesn't populate the cloud_v2 attribute

Tags: azure, chef-infra, bootstrapping, ohai-gem

Running Chef's `knife bootstrap` command successfully populates the `cloud_v2` attribute via Ohai when I bootstrap VMs created on Google Cloud and Rackspace, but on Azure VMs bootstraping via knife leaves the `cloud_v2` hash very empty -- it only gets populated with one attribute: `provder: azure`.

In contrast, Ohai successfully populates Google Cloud and Rackspace nodes with something that looks like:

`cloud_v2:
  public_ipv4_addrs
    0: xxx.xxx.xxx.85
  local_ipv4_addrs
    0: 10.240.0.2
  provider: gce
  local_hostname: myhostname.projectname.internal
  public_ipv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.85
  local_ipv4: 10.240.0.2`

Is this a bug in Azure's Ohai plugin?  How can I get the Knife bootstrap command to include more of the default Ohai attributes?  Most specifically I need the public_ipv4 so I can use this attribute to run the `knife ssh` commands.

Comment: What is the output of running `sudo chef-client -l debug -VV`?

Comment: @Ivan `-vv`  gives `invalid option: -VV (OptionParser::InvalidOption)` along with a stacktrace (is that last argument a valid chef option?).  Running `sudo chef-client -l debug -v` (with a single lowercase "v") outputs my Chef version which is `Chef: 12.16.42`

Comment: then `sudo chef-client -l debug` please, I don't remember the options but the idea is to make recipes log as much stuff as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohai only supports [limited auto-detection of Azure](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/azure.rb#L30-L32). If you touch the hint file (`mydir -p /etc/chef/ohai/hints && touch /etc/chef/ohai/hints/azure.json`) it should see things better. This is generally handled for you automatically if you use the relevant `knife-$cloud` plugin but with plain `knife bootstrap` you need to do it either via the `--hint` option or manually as above.